# Python class and objects within another function

Tags: python, class, object

I’m trying to learn how to utilize class and objects within my Python code. I'm totally overwhelmed by the fact that is is suppose to be a begginingers class and I got this assignment where if something like this:

Class name is IPAdress and there I want properties IP, hostname, ASN and ISP. Also, it has a method which creates similar print like this:

```
IP: 85.76.129.254
Hostname: 85-76-129-254-nat.elisa-mobile.fi
ASN: 719
ISP: Elisa Mobile
```

Method can be named as PrintDetails.

Once the class is ready, I want to use it within my Osio9 function as following

1. Function asks user to input IP, hostname, ASN and ISP. Object is created according to this information.
2. Object is added to list (initially empty) and information is printed by using the PrintDetails -method
3. After this user is asked if he/she wants to create a new IP and if answer is yes -> repeat the above process (ask for input), add the new object to a list and print all information from the list with PrintDetails
4. After input, the list is looped through and it calls each IPAddress object with PrintDetails -method. (Print can look like the example above)
5. If user doesn’t want to continue inputting IP-addresses, exit the function

I have no clue how to proceed and answer I receive from my teacher is to look from google so here I am.

```
class IPAddress:  ##define class
        def __init__(self, IP, hostname, ASN, ISP):
            self.ip = ip
            self.hostname = hostname
            self.asn = asn
            self.isp = isp

        def PrintDetails(self):  ## construction method
            print("IP-address: " + str(self.ip) + " | Hostname: " + str(self.hostname) + " | ASN: " + str(self.asn) + "ISP: " + str(self.isp))                   


def Osio9():

    addresses = []

    while(true):
       
        ip = str (input("Enter IP address: "))  #ask for user input
        hostname = str (input("Enter Hostname: "))
        asn = str (input("Enter ASN: "))
        isp = str (input("Enter ISP: "))

        address = IPAddress
        address.isp = isp
        addresses.append(address)

        for IPAddress in addresses:
            IPAddress.PrintDetails(self)
     
            
  
 #           continueInput = str (input("Do you want to add more IP-addresses (y/n): "))
 #               if (continueInput == "y"): 
 #                  return addresses
 #
 #               else break
```

Comment: The class is correctly defined except the 'for IPAddress in IPAddress' which is absolutely useless. Look at the definition of the == and != method (eq and ne methods) for a class and define them. The idea is to get the user input; create an IPAddress object and then check if it is already in the list of IPAddress object. If it's not, then add it to the list of IPAdress objects. Try to update your question with these additional tips first; and I will then provide you with a piece of code and explanations on the ideas/difference I will implement.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand

Comment: I edited the code though

Comment: You can find a more detailed version in my answer. Test each part individually to understand what they are doing. I saw that you changed the names of the attributes from capital letters to lower letters. It's good practice as capital letters variable should be reserved for globals/variables imported into other programs. I didn't really reread my answer, so there might be some typos left. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw your last update and there are some good ideas in it. Here is one version of the program, which does not completely correspond to your assignment as the main execution is not within a loop but in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement which will execute only when the program is called directly, and not when it is imported or when function part of this program are imported. I highly encourage you to try a small part of the code, one at a time, and then to adapt it to your specific need.

Let's go piece by piece:

```
#%% Definition of IPAddress
class IPAddress:
    def __init__(self, ip, hostname, asn, isp):
        self.ip = ip
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.asn = asn
        self.isp = isp

    def prettyprint(self):
        str2print = f' | IP: {self.ip}\n' +\
                    f' | Hostname: {self.hostname}\n' +\
                    f' | ASN: {self.asn}\n' +\
                    f' | ISP: {self.isp}\n'
        print (str2print)
    
    def __key(self):
        """
        key method to uniquely identify an object IPAddress.
        I defined it as a tuple of the 4 main attributes, but if one of them is
        unique it could be directly used as a key.
        """
        return (self.ip, self.hostname, self.asn, self.isp)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """ == comparison method."""
        return isinstance(self, type(other)) and self.__key() == other.__key()
    
    def __ne__(self, other):
        """ != comparison method."""
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __hash__(self):
        """Makes the object hashable. Sets can now be used on IPAddress."""
        return hash(self.__key())
```

I am using spyder as an IDE, and the symbol `#%%` creates sections of code, very similar to matlab, which can be executed in the current console by doing Right-Click -> Run Cell.

I changed the print function to make it more explicit. Strings object can be denoted by 3 symbols: `'str'`, `"str"`, `"""str"""`. Additionnaly, a flag in front can change the behavior of the string. The most usefull ones are `f` and `r`.

Formatting a string with either `.format()` method or the `f` flag.

```
value = 1
str1 = 'string to format with value v = {}'.format(value)
str2 = f'string to format with value v = {value}'
```

You can print both string to see that they are equivalent. The flag `f` is similar to a `.format()` call. It allows the element within the brackets `{}` to be executed before the print. It is especially usefull when you format a string with multiple values.

```
v1 = 1
v2 = 2
str1 = 'string to format with value v = {} and {}'.format(v1, v2)
str2 = f'string to format with value v = {v1} and {v2}'
```

I still chose to split the sring into 4 strings and to add them together for a cleaner look of the code. The backslash `\` at the end of each line allows python to consider the current line and the next one as the same line. It's a line-split character.

*N.B: If you want to know what the flag `r` does, look into the escape character ;) `r` flag is especially usefull when working with paths.*

Objects can be compared together. For instace, if you try `5==3`, python will return `False` because the integer object `5` is different from the integer object `3`. You can implement the `==` and `!=` method in any object/class you develop. To do so, I first define a unique key for this object in the function `__key()`. Then the function `__eq__` implements `==` and returns `True` if both objects compared are created from the same class and have the same key. The method `__ne__` implements `!=` and returns `True` if `__eq__` is not `True`.

*N.B: I also added the hash method to make the object hashable. Once the key is define, creating a hash is trivial, since the idea is to be able to uniquely identify each object, which is also done by the key. This definition allows the use of sets, for instance to check if a list has multiple occurence of the same object.*

```
def add_IPAddress(ListOfIPAddresses, IPAddress):
    """
    Function adding IPAddress to ListOfIPAddresses if IPAddress is not already
    in ListOfIPAddresses.
    """
    if IPAddress not in ListOfIPAddresses:
        ListOfIPAddresses.append(IPAddress)
        print ('IP Address appended:')
        IPAddress.prettyprint()

def input_IPAddress():
    """
    Ask a user input to create an IPAddress object.
    """
    ip = input("Enter IP address: ")
    hostname = input("Enter Hostname: ")
    asn = input("Enter ASN: ")
    isp = input("Enter ISP: ")
    return IPAddress(ip, hostname, asn, isp)
```

Then I splitted the input from the user and the addition to a list of objects into 2 different functions. The function `input()` already returns a string, thus I removed the `str()` call to convert.

*N.B: Watchout when asking users to input numbers, usually you forget that the input is a string and then your code raises an error because you forget to convert the string to integer or float.*

*Improvements: I didn't do it here, but usually when using user input, you have to check if the input given is correct. Some simple syntax checks (e.g. the number of '.' characters in the ipadress) can already improve the robustness of a piece of code. You could also use regular expressions with `regex` to check if the input is conform.*

The `query_yes_no()` is a clean yes/no util which I copied from somewhere.. I usually place it in a util module: folder within the environment path named `util` with a `__init__.py` file. More information if you look into the creation of python module.

```
#%% Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ListOfIPAddresses = list()
    
    while True:
        if not query_yes_no('Do you want to input IP Address?'):
            break
        
        ListOfIPAddresses.append(input_IPAddress())
    
    for ipaddress in ListOfIPAddresses:
        ipaddress.prettyprint()
        print ('--------------------------') # Just pretting a separator
```

Finally, in the main part, an infinite `while` loop is broke only if the user replies `no` (or any of the other negative keyworkds defined in `query_yes_no()`). Until it is broken, the user will be asked to add a new IPAddress to the list ListOfIPAddresses which will be added if it is not already present inside.

Full code snippet:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

#%% Definition of IPAddress
class IPAddress:
    def __init__(self, ip, hostname, asn, isp):
        self.ip = ip
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.asn = asn
        self.isp = isp

    def prettyprint(self):
        str2print = f' | IP: {self.ip}\n' +\
                    f' | Hostname: {self.hostname}\n' +\
                    f' | ASN: {self.asn}\n' +\
                    f' | ISP: {self.isp}\n'
        print (str2print)
    
    def __key(self):
        """
        key method to uniquely identify an object IPAddress.
        I defined it as a tuple of the 4 main attributes, but if one of them is
        unique it could be directly used as a key.
        """
        return (self.ip, self.hostname, self.asn, self.isp)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """ == comparison method."""
        return isinstance(self, type(other)) and self.__key() == other.__key()
    
    def __ne__(self, other):
        """ != comparison method."""
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __hash__(self):
        """Makes the object hashable. Sets can now be used on IPAddress."""
        return hash(self.__key())

#%% Functions
def add_IPAddress(ListOfIPAddresses, IPAddress):
    """
    Function adding IPAddress to ListOfIPAddresses if IPAddress is not already
    in ListOfIPAddresses.
    """
    if IPAddress not in ListOfIPAddresses:
        ListOfIPAddresses.append(IPAddress)
        print ('IP Address appended:')
        IPAddress.prettyprint()

def input_IPAddress():
    """
    Ask a user input to create an IPAddress object.
    """
    ip = input("Enter IP address: ")
    hostname = input("Enter Hostname: ")
    asn = input("Enter ASN: ")
    isp = input("Enter ISP: ")
    return IPAddress(ip, hostname, asn, isp)

#%% Util
def query_yes_no(question, default="yes"):
    """Ask a yes/no question via raw_input() and return their answer.

    "question" is a string that is presented to the user.
    "default" is the presumed answer if the user just hits <Enter>.
        It must be "yes" (the default), "no" or None (meaning
        an answer is required of the user).

    The "answer" return value is True for "yes" or False for "no".
    """
    valid = {"yes": True, "y": True, "ye": True,
             "no": False, "n": False}
    if default is None:
        prompt = " [y/n] "
    elif default == "yes":
        prompt = " [Y/n] "
    elif default == "no":
        prompt = " [y/N] "
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid default answer: '%s'" % default)

    while True:
        sys.stdout.write(question + prompt)
        choice = input().lower()
        if default is not None and choice == '':
            return valid[default]
        elif choice in valid:
            return valid[choice]
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' "
                             "(or 'y' or 'n').\n")

#%% Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ListOfIPAddresses = list()
    
    while True:
        if not query_yes_no('Do you want to input IP Address?'):
            break
        
        ListOfIPAddresses.append(input_IPAddress())
    
    for ipaddress in ListOfIPAddresses:
        ipaddress.prettyprint()
        print ('--------------------------') # Just pretting a separator
```

Comment: you're totally awesome and your input via comments it's wayyy more than I was able to get from our teacher! Big +1

Comment: @SakariTyynelä You are welcome. SO has a system of upvote/downvote + accepting the answers. I encourage you to use it as much as possible to promote good answers and to 'close' your questions. It's located at the top left of a question/answer.

Comment: Will do sir! Thanks again for your input, this was encouraging.